# Morris.js not rendering correct in w3css slideshow

Tags: javascript, morris.js, w3-css

I am trying to make a slideshow of 2 Morris.js charts with w3css slideshow.

(I used this: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_dots and replace the images with 2 Morris.js charts with hardcoded data)

first chart is drawn correctly but the second one is somehow croped.

What I have tried is to store the Morris charts in local vars and redraw the charts when the slide changes, but still no luck.

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px">
    <div class="mySlides" id="graph1" style="width:100%"></div>
    <div class="mySlides" id="graph2" style="width:100%"></div>
</div>

<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-section">
    <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮ Prev</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next ❯</button>
  </div>
  <button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(1)">1</button> 
  <button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(2)">2</button> 
</div>

<script>

Morris.Line({
  element: 'graph1',
  data: week_data,
  xkey: 'period',
  ykeys: ['licensed'],
  labels: ['Licensed']
});
Morris.Line({
  element: 'graph2',
  data: week_data,
  xkey: 'period',
  ykeys: ['licensed'],
  labels: ['Licensed']
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It seems that I cannot paste the entire html so, the rest of the code can be found in here: 

 https://jsfiddle.net/d5p16q2z/1/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to resize the width of the SVG element. When I have such problems, I do something like this:

```
$('#graph1 svg').width($('div.mySlides').width());
```